# How to Sort Gmail by sender?

Tags: javascript, gmail

I have sorted all emails in Gmail by sender with JavaScript using JQuery, XPath and TinySort

```
function sort(){
  $mails = jQuery(document).xpath("//tr[td/div/span[@email]]");
  $mails.tsort("td.yX>div.yW>span",{attr:'email'});
}
```

Now when I select an email, Gmail scrolls to the original location of that email. And if I shift select a few sorted emails, all emails between the original email locations get selected.

I have tried debugging Gmail in both Chrome and Firefox but can not find the indexes.

Comment: I'm not sure what version of jQuery you're using, but to my knowledge, there's no native `.xpath()` method in the latest versions of jQuery.

Comment: Sorry didn't mention. I am using XPath plugin as well.